# Thread safety on libc calls on LynxOS 2.4

Tags: c, multithreading, thread-safety, posix, lynxos

I'm right now doing a project on LynxOS 2.4, and I have several calls made by multiple threads to some C standard libraries. Among the functions that I need to control are, mainly, file operations such as 'open', 'read' and 'write'.

Now, in all POSIX compliant systems after POSIX.1 2001 all these calls have to be thread safe, but LynxOS 2.4 was developed way before that standard, and is compliant with some older version of POSIX that didn't request this.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to finding out which C standard library calls are thread-safe and which aren't in this OS. I've searched through most of the official documentation and haven't found much.

Thanks in advance guys.